# Can I delete the Copy Constructor in Members of a Union?

Tags: c++, unions, c++03

The compilation of bitfields in C++ is implementation dependant - they might not be compiled as expected if it is more efficient to do otherwise. Unfortunately, this is undesirable when dealing with rigid standards requiring bitfields to be organized exactly (such as when data is transferred between devices). I tried to make a more exact bitfield structure for use in a unions:

```
template< unsigned char BIT_COUNT , unsigned char OFFSET >
struct Bitfield
{
protected:
    unsigned char data;
        // Get and Set Functions
public:
    operator unsigned char () const
    {
        return ( data >> OFFSET ) & ( ( 1 < BIT_COUNT ) -1 );
    }
    Bitfield& operator = ( unsigned char  value )
    {
        const unsigned char mask = ( ( 1 << BIT_COUNT ) - 1 ) << OFFSET;
        data &= ~mask;
        data |= ( value << OFFSET ) & mask;
        return *this;
    }

};

union Bitfield_Test
{
    Bitfield< 8 , 0 > raw;
    Bitfield< 4 , 0 > flagset_1;
    Bitfield< 1 , 0 > flag_a;
    Bitfield< 1 , 1 > flag_b;
    Bitfield< 1 , 2 > flag_c;
    Bitfield< 1 , 3 > flag_d;
    Bitfield< 4 , 4 > flagset_2;
    Bitfield< 1 , 4 > flag_w;
    Bitfield< 1 , 5 > flag_x;
    Bitfield< 1 , 6 > flag_y;
    Bitfield< 1 , 7 > flag_z;
};

void Test()
{
    Bitfield_Test test1;
    test1.raw =      1 << 6;
    test1.flag_a =   1;

    Bitfield_Test test2;
    test2.raw =      0;
    test2.flag_a =   test1.flag_a =   1;
}
```

Unfortunately, my solution does not behave as expected when transferring data from one union member to another. It sets the entire union to the value of the other instead of just its member. I suspect that the culprit is the default copy constructor. Unfortunately, unions will not allow structures that override the copy constructor as members, even if no implementation is defined.

Is there any trick or hack I can use to prevent the compilation of the default copy constructor in this instance?

Comment: Read [five things to know about C++11 unions](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=556)

Comment: While this is a helpful resources, I'm stuck using Visual Studio 2010 which seems to lack the C++11 features recommended by your article. I suppose I could have specified, but I preferred to keep my question open ended to be helpful to others.

Comment: Then, tag your question with C++03 or C++98

Comment: Thanks for the advice.